# datetime picker validations

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two datetimepickers (DateofBirth(DOB) and DateofIssue(DOI)) and i need to validate these  datetime pickers there should be 18 years difference between DateofBirth(DOB) and DateOfIssue(DOI). How to do this. Please suggest me ideas

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime birth;
DateTime issue;
if (birth.AddYears(18) > issue) {
    throw new Exception("Not 18 years between birth and issue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
int diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalYears;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DateDiff** Function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.71).aspx